# Accessing React prop array in component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to map across an array stored in props in my React component. The problem is that I keep getting an error stating that 'step is not defined', even when I have an array of steps defined such as below. Any thoughts on what I am doing incorrectly? Thanks in advance!

```
render() {
const protocol = this.props.protocol;
const steps = protocol.steps;
let stepList = null;

if (steps != null) {
  stepList = <ul>
    steps.map(
      step => <li>{step.title}</li>
    )
  </ul>;
} else {
  stepList = 'Do not display list';
}

return (
  <div className="protocols-detail">
    List of steps for {protocol.title}
    { stepList }

  </div>
);
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is in this line, you forgot to use `{}`, to use any js code inside `HTML` element always use `{}` try this:

```
stepList = <ul>
    {
       steps.map(
         (step,i) => <li key={i}>{step.title}</li>
       )
    }
  </ul>;
```

One more thing always assign the unique `key` to each items when creating the `ui elements dynamically` in the `loop`.

Comment: Thank you! I am still in the learning process and I appreciate the help.

Comment: glad, to help you :), if u r beginner in reactjs then read this one, atleast basic things, it will help you alot :)  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `steps.map` in `{ }` (inside `<ul></ul>` tags)

so it should be:

```
render() {
const protocol = this.props.protocol;
const steps = protocol.steps;
let stepList = null;

if (steps != null) {
  stepList = <ul>
    {steps.map(
      step => <li>{step.title}</li>
    )}
  </ul>;
} else {
  stepList = 'Do not display list';
}

return (
  <div className="protocols-detail">
    List of steps for {protocol.title}
    { stepList }

  </div>
);
```